# How to switch from child activity to home activity in tabhost

Tags: android, tabs, android-activity

I am implementing tab in my App. For that I made a class to handle the activities inside the tab. My problem is I started some activities one after another like A, B, C, D. Now I want to comeback to Activity A from D, and other activites like B, C and D should be destroyed. Please help me to implement this. Here is the code I am using to handle activities...

```
public class TabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup {

protected Context mCTX;
protected ArrayList<String> mIdList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(mIdList == null){
        mIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    //set context
    mCTX = this;

}

public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent){
    Id+= System.currentTimeMillis();
    Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));

    if (window != null) {
        mIdList.add(Id);
        setContentView(window.getDecorView());
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int length = mIdList.size();
    if(length > 0){
        Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(mIdList.get(length-1));
        current.finish();
    }

}

@Override
public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {

    LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
    int index = mIdList.size()-1;

    if (index < 1) {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    manager.destroyActivity(mIdList.get(index), true);
    mIdList.remove(index);
    index--;
    String lastId = mIdList.get(index);
    Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
    Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent);
    setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
}


}
```

When I Start activity I will use the following code.

```
Intent locIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,SomeActivity.class);
TabGroupActivity parent = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
parent.startChildActivity("some id", locIntent);
```

One more doubt I have...How to switch an activity in one tab to an activity in another tab.
Thanks in advance

Comment: still searching for a solution

Answer (score 5):

Don't use Activities inside a TabHost, its a waste of memory. I'd rather use fragments instead. You can easily add them to the TabHost. This is a good tutorial:

http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/android-tabs-viewpager-swipe-able-tabs-ftw/

Comment: I think you are tring to make an iOS like TabBar navigation into your Android app. It's not a very good idea. Try to re-think your UI in an Android way. If you have a look on most android apps, when you have a TabHost, it only works on a single level (the root one), when you go deeper, the apps usually start a new activity without a TabHost.

Comment: I am trying to make an Ios Like tabbar. Client wants it like that only.. Everything is working fine by using ActivityManager. I wan it to go to the home activity from child activity and kill all other activities between these two activities.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you set the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` for new intent you are calling to go back to an Activity which was started earlier .

you need to set your launchMode to multiple instance in manifest file for that Activity, and use only FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

As stated the theory of FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.

I have used it and it works perfectly fine , So Please let me know if it makes sense to you or if you face any problem in implementing it.

Comment: I tried it, but no use...normally this way is working for me. Here I am using Tab and Activitygroup to handle all the activities. Here it is not working..

Comment: Then there must be some thing wrong with your ActivityGroup class as its written on Official Android site  and it worked for me .. can you paste your activity group code here .

Answer (score 0):

The following link is very iseful
http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/android-tabs-viewpager-swipe-able-tabs-ftw/